# OTA update limitations with custom ROM?

Tags: ota-update, launcher, android-tv

I want to do some experimenting with an Android TV stick and want to ask some questions beforehand -- that I couldn't find answers to already here on SO.

Any advice is appreciated!

1. Is it possible to flash the ROM, to start with my customized Android TV launcher? i.e. like [Android TV Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.leanbacklauncher&hl=en)
2. If YES to the above, could I have the OS periodically check for updates on my **OWN CUSTOM SERVER**, to prompt to update the OS / launcher itself?

I am a little confused, because as I understand it from the official documentation, flashing the ROM places restrictions on OTA updates.

Surely I can update my launcher or over-write certain files fetched from my own server?

Answer (score 1):

It would not seem to make sense to flash a ROM for a customized android TV launcher - all you need is something to automatically start your app when you boot - maybe something like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autostart

If you build your own ROM you can make it do whatever you want - including check for updates on your own server - this is probably not trivial, and anyway, where would the upgrades come from.

If you flash your ROM you will no longer get OTA updates as you are no longer running the software associated with the OTA updates.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on the ROM you are going to use.

You won't get any OTA updates from the manufacturer. However there are ROMs out there, which use the original (hacked) OTA interface to provide their own OTA updates. So it's definitely possible, but I highly doubt, that you can easily modify that. I've had that functionality on my HTC One for example.

Also some custom roms provide a client from where you can update.

All those updates however are not really "OTA", as they will always have to boot into your custom recovery and install it from there.

If it's just for having a kind of automation I would go for an app like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=de), AutomateIt or Llama, which provide a great benefit if it comes to automation of things like start up behaviour.